# How to configure sync_gateway with Couchbase server

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to connect sync gateway to the couchbase server.

By following the below
[Link](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/sync-gateway/running-sync-gateway/index.html)
, but the problem is I am getting the error when run the command:

`$ ./sync_gateway config.json` as shown the screenshot attach below:

[image]

Comment: How did you install Sync Gateway? It should be an archive that you expand. Than you should have a bin folder containing the sync_gateway executable.

Comment: @LaurentDoguin Ok, I have installed Sync_Gateway. and I am following your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in wrong directory change the directory to the installation location.

cd /opt/couchbase-sync-gateway/bin

then run following command.

./sync_gateway

for more information visit to [link](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/sync-gateway/running-sync-gateway/index.html)